# How to set EditText cursor style in 2.3

Tags: android

I am trying to set the style of the edittext cursor ion 2.3.I am trying to use the property android:textCursorDrawable but this is applicable for 3.0 and above.
I also tried to make the folder layout-v12 and then used this property but still getting error.
Kindly suggest any solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Waza_Be actually android:textCursorDrawable is not present in 2.3 sdk so its showing error( mehtod not found) and when i change the targetsdk all my layouts got changed please suggest me how to do that.

Comment: You should always target the highest sdk you have tested your app. If the layout changed, that's another issue.